# How to change special character "\" in a text file with replace

Tags: java

I need to change some things in a big .rtf. I do it correctly in another files with another text changing, but in the text has something like this "\line". I want to change it to "\par"

I know the '\' is special character, and I can't use simple `.replace("\line", "\par")`. I tried  the `.replace("\\line", "\\par")`.

Neither worked, is there a way to do this? I can't use simple `.replace("line", "par")` because some words have the line between but without the "\". I only need to change when line has a "\" before

Answer (score 4):

Strings are *immutable*

```
line = line.replace("\\line", "\\par");
```

Comment: Worked fine too, but its strange i tried this, using \\, but dont worked, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\` in the regex as `\\`. However each of *these* needs to be escaped in the string. You'll need a full regex:

```
replaceAll("\\\\line", "\\\\par");
```

4 backslashes are turned into 2 `\` characters in the string during compiler parsing, and `\\` is parsed by the regex engine as a single *literal* backslash.

Comment: @BackSlash Given the attempt to use double backslashes failing I'm assuming the issue is another set thereof missing. `replaceAll` should be used anyway.

Comment: @BackSlash Edited to correct `String#replaceAll`, also the OP should use `repalceFirst` where appropriate.

Comment: Seen, however i think Reimenus answer is the right one, probably the OP is thinking that simply calling the replace does the trick, but strings are immutable so he has to reassign the string

Comment: @BackSlash That is something that I have not and would not have inferred from the limited info given by the OP.